# ajaxcontoltoolkit not working

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.5

I tried to make ajaxcontroltoolkit work with visual studio 2012 and asp.net 4.5, but it never works

I always get error :

AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

I changed the ScriptManager to ToolkitScriptManager,but I still get the same error.
I uploaded the project at the link below, please any one help me in this as the hole project depend on it.

the default page has example with ajax toolkit control, also login page, both fail with the error upove

link to Project

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g43f0a32df74171f99992249134da0707f6b9f9572

Comment: I hope any one can help me on this please.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for it, the problem was in Dll name "Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll", you have to remove it from web project references and delete it from Bin directory of the web project, after that the ajaxtoolkit works fine

Answer (score 1):

A new release has been released. Download from this site: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/100852 
Then to install the new release follow these steps: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/09/20/september-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit I have just installed it and everything works so far I can tell. Hope this helps.